# Content Ontology Design patterns

Tags: design-patterns

I need some information about the history for CPDs?

If any one have information about the relation between **CPDs** and **software pattern**.

Answer (score 0):

Ontology Design Patterns are mainly used in ontology (e.g. Gene Ontology) design for modelling a domain.

Software patterns can be domain driven design patterns, architectural patterns, object oriented design patterns, etc. Domain driven design patterns are primarily used for modelling a domain in Software. Others can be used, but they are not specifically intended for modelling a domain.